# How to share data between Virtual machine and host machine?

Tags: virtual-machine

I have install Windows7 32 bit virtual machine, and Win7 64bit as a host machine . I want to share data between virtual machine and host machine. How I can share the data between both machines?

I am using VMWare to run virtual machine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/running_sharefold_ws.html

You may install VMWare Tools to share folders to share file between guest OS and host OS.
In above article, Windows 7 is not included, you can share file across windows 7.